# Can't fulfill a get request using express.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, get

Here is my server code:

```
express
  .Router()
 .post('/authFB', async (req, res) => {
   // const agent = express();
    req.query = {
      client_id: 'ID',
      redirect_uri: `https://localhost:3000/`,
      client_secret: 'SECRET',
      code: Object.keys(req.body)[0]
    };

    req.baseUrl = `https://graph.facebook.com`

    const v = await req.get(`/v3.2/oauth/access_token`)
     v.body
  })
```

Problem I'm having is 'v' is always undefined - I've tested the facebook request via PostMan and it's working - it seems though my get request is never fulfilled.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. `req` is an object describing the request made to the express server. It isn't an object from which you make an outgoing request.

Comment: I can't get the above code to compile (at least not without putting in more effort than I'm willing to guess at what should go in the gaps). Please provide a [mcve]. Starting with [hello world](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) and adding your code to it would probably be a good bet.

Comment: @Quentin What is an object from which I make outgoing requests then - because certainly this doesn't currently work?

Comment: Is it even possible to make a request from the server?

Comment: node-fetch for example

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions — Yes. There are hordes of helper libraries for making HTTP requests from Node.js. It comes with [http.request](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) is built-in.

Answer (score 0):

I think that should be more like this

```
const got = require('got'); // I am using got for api call
express
    .Router()
    .post('/authFB', async (req, res) => {
        // const agent = express();
        const query = {
          client_id: 'ID',
          redirect_uri: `https://localhost:3000/`,
          client_secret: 'SECRET',
          code: Object.keys(req.body)[0]
        };
        const baseUrl = `https://graph.facebook.com`

        const v = await got(`${baseUrl}/v3.2/oauth/access_token`, { query });
        console.log(v.body);
        res.send(v.body);
    });
```

Here the data is fetched by 'got' and the response can be sent back to the client or use it in whatever way possible.

What you are doing here would be an antipattern because you are trying to edit the express request object which is not recommended unless used for authentication and other actions which are required for application level.

Also, that req is express.Request type. It doesn't have a get() property on it. Check [this](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req) for your reference.

Hope this explains your question well enough!!!
cheers :)